# Views not updating until entire click function has finished

Tags: java, android

I have a save button that performs a relatively slow task synchronously before finishing the activity. When the button is pressed, I want to immediately show a ProgressBar and hide everything else. My problem is that my calls to setVisibility at the very beginning of my method don't update the UI until after the long task has been performed; my ProgressBar only shows a fraction of a second before the activity finishes. Why could this be happening?

```
public void save(View view) {
  Date time = new Date();
  view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
  progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
  // Logged time is about 20 ms
  Log.i("Time", String.valueOf(new Date().getTime() - time.getTime()));
  try {
    // Long synchronous operation
    document.save();
  }
  catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("Exception", e.getMessage());
  }
  // ProgressBar turns visible here, after a few seconds
  Log.i("Time", String.valueOf(new Date().getTime() - time.getTime()));
  finish();
}
```

Comment: You'll have to call the document.save() method inside another thread as it is currently making use of the main thread, thereby blocking it.

Comment: @BluRe.CN If I understand correctly, calling setVisibility does not actually update the UI, it's another process taking the main thread every 1/60th second, and when this occurs, it is already too late because the main thread has had time to move on to document.save().